# Посчитать сколько в этом диапазоне простых чисел на С языке

Tags: c, простые-числа

```
#include<stdio.h>

int countPrimeNumber(int from, int to);
```

//принимает диапазон чисел от from до to, посчитать сколько в этом диапазоне простых чисел

Подскажите как подобраться к началу задачи, не могу понять(
нужно использовать цикл while И условные операторы только(

Comment: Если абсолютно точное количество - то пересчитывать. Можно иметь предварительно посчитанные реперные точки - будет быстрее.

Comment: а если цифры просто любые

Comment: Еще вариант - пожалуй, будет быстрее - строить решето Эратосфена...

Comment: Какие ограничения на диапазон? Рекомендую посмотреть этот вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567608/195342

Comment: от 1 к примеру и до 100

Comment: Тю, и из-за этого возиться?... Мы тут прикидываем, как до 2 миллиардов... До 100 и говорить не о чем - просто перепроверяйте каждое число, и вперед...

Comment: ну это пример 
ну не указано числа точные 
это просто я просто придумал числа наугад и все 
у нас просто 1 урок по циклам и такое задание дали

Comment: Тогда поищите тут по сайту - это очень частst вопросы. Например, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0

Comment: но я думаю что цифры типо 2 миллиардов это прям уже сложная задачка)) для меня и понять тоже я думаю еще сложно будет

Comment: Просто посмотрите на вопросы по ссылке, что я указал. Там множество раз писалась функция проверки простоты числа. Дальше - ваша задача - цикл от первого числа до второго с проверкой каждого числа на простоту, и подсчет количества простых.

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно

1. написать свою функцию `bool isPrime(int)`, которая будет определять является ли число простым или нет
2. пройти с помощью `for` от `from` до `to` и для каждого числа вызвать `isPrime`, так определите является ли число простым
3. при каждом найденном простом числе увеличивать счетчик чисел на 1

А если нужно определить ПРИМЕРНО кол-во простых чисел, то достаточно сделать следующее:

```
const int count = to / log(to) - from / log(from);
```

когда у вас `from` и `to` будут стремиться к бесконечности, то вы получите точное значение, а так - только приближенное

еще точнее было бы

```
const int count = li(to) - li(from);
```

где `li` - интегральный логарифм, но его нет в стандартной библиотеки, так что особенно не поиспользовать :)

Comment: Достаточно проверять только нечетные числа

Comment: @avp, конечно, только если `from < 2`, а так если числа огромные, то можно вбить таблицу скажем из 1000 первых простых чисел и идти с соответствующим шагом

Comment: Все же мне кажется, решето Эратосфена будет быстрее...

Comment: @Harry, вот только он сдохнет на числе 10000000000 просто из-за нехватки памяти (у кого-то раньше у кого-то позже в зависимости от компа) :)

Comment: Ну, `int` в 5 раз меньше :) Давайте мах на мах? Вы пишете свое решение, смотрим время до 2000000000, я свое. Сравниваем...

Comment: от 1 к примеру и до 100  проверить

Comment: @Harry, т.е. подсчитать все простые числа от `2` до `2000000000`?

Comment: Да. от 1 до 100 - как вы понимаете, это не проверка :) Правда, я не обратил внимания на язык, и писал на С++...

Comment: ну против вашего сегментированного сита можно конечно пободаться из спортивного интереса, хотя и само сито можно ускорить

Comment: Конечно, можно :) Оно ж написано со скоростью набора текста... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
 
using namespace std;
 
const int N     = 2000000000;
const int sqrtN = 44721;
 
vector<bool> primes(N+1,true);
 
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    primes[1] = false;
    for(int i = 0; i <= N; i+= 2) primes[i] = false;
    primes[2] = true;
 
    for(int i = 3; i <= sqrtN; i += 2)
    {
        if (primes[i] == false) continue;
        for(int j = i*i; j <= N; j += i)
        {
            primes[j] = false;
        }
    }

    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        if (primes[i]) ++total;
    }
    cout << total << endl;
}
```

На *тупом* решете Эратосфена, с не самым эффективным `vector<bool>` у меня для 2000000000 считало 19 секунд.

Запасы для оптимизации, конечно, есть, но небольшие.

Кто напишет для сравнения переборный метод?