# Ошибка при реализации решета Эратосфена на c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Необходимо найти все простые числа, не превосходящие заданного, используя решето Эратосфена. При запуске кода в VS 2019 вылезает ошибка.

[image: .]

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* parr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        parr[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i * i; j <= n; j += i)
        {
            parr[j] = -1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (parr[i] != -1)
        {
            cout << parr[i] << " ";

        }
    }
    delete[] parr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Тут не принято просто добавлять "решено" к заголовку. Если вам помог один из оставленных ответов, жмякните галочку слева от него, чтобы отметить вопрос как решенный. Если нашли ответ сами, пишите свой собственный ответ и ставьте галочку на него.

Answer (score 4):

```
int* parr = new int[n];
```

Выделили массив из `n` элементов, но

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

обращаетесь к `n+1` элементу. Выход за границы массива как минимум...

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам готовый вариант на векторе (он меньше массива жрет).

Нарыл где-то в сети и допилил немного.

Вывод закомментирован.

Максимум N (<= 18 446 744 073 709 551 615) - это теоретически с чем оно можнт работать. На деле я с больше чем 10 млрд не тестировал. Компилировал в командной строке MinGW\bin\c++ и MinGW\bin\g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <numeric>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "russian");

    std::cout << "Введите N (<= 18 446 744 073 709 551 615) ";
    unsigned long long n;
    cin >> n;
    auto start = clock();
    vector<bool> v(n + 1, true);
    v[0] = false;
    v[1] = false;
    
    unsigned long long pp;
    for (unsigned long long p = 2; p <= n; ++p)
    {
        pp = p*p;
        if(pp > n or p >= 4294967296) break;
        if(!v[p]) continue;
        for (unsigned long long d = pp; d <= n; d += p)
        {
            if(!v[d]) continue;
            v[d] = false;
        }
    }
    
    auto finish = clock();
    unsigned long long count = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::cout << "Количество простых чисел от 2 (включительно) до " << n << " (включительно) " << count << std::endl;
 
    std::cout << "На работу алгоритма потрачено секунд "
        << static_cast<double>(finish - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

    /*
    //Вывод простых чисел на консоль
    unsigned long long num = 0;
    for (const auto &flag : v)
    {
        if (flag)
        {
            // std::cout << num << " ";
        }
        ++num;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    */
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите на ответы к этому вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/567608/195342 Интересно сравнить время, кстати.

Comment: @Harry Что я там должен увидеть?

Comment: Более эффективный код.

Comment: @Harry Я штук 10 вариантов перепробовал. В разных ЯП. С разными системами счисления. С различным представлением больших чисел. срр с вектором для решета Эратосфена наиболее оптимальный по комбинации/отношению скорости, съедаемой памяти, и сложности\простоте реализации. Например прм вычеркивании "дешевле" сделать 2 прохода с вычеркиванием 2^n и 3^n, чем на каждой итерации просчитывать сдвиг 6n+/-1 (не говоря уже о поиске в прогрессиях с d=30+[1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29] ). Для факторизации да, перебор - это наименее эффективное решение, а для получения всех простых в интервале вполне.

Comment: А вообще, в моем варианте вроде уже нечего оптимизировать на человеческом уровне - больше sqrt оно не берет, цикл вычеркивания совершается только с простыми числами, писваивание "координате вектора"  false быстрее, чем добавлять/удалять в/из массив(а). Остальное, если что-то надумается, уже будет касаться не алгоритма, а конкретных приколов языка.

Comment: там выше "2 прохода с вычеркиванием 2n и 3n", а не степень. Очепятался малость.

Comment: Судя по сообщению *`"error: taking address of temporary"`* при попытке узнать адрес элемента `vector<bool> v(n + 1, true);` этот `v` реализован как строка бит. Не пробовали заменить на `vector<char>` (видимо займет в 8 раз больше памяти) и сравнить скорость?

Comment: @avp Не пробовал. Я вообще с сишным вариантом долго не ковырялся, т.к. не могу похвастаться глубокими знаниями этого языка, да и памяти у меня на ноуте может не хватить. И к тому же после нескольких дней ковыряния с простыми числами уже не было желания больше экспериментировать. Но мне кажется, что быстрее не будет. А вот для хранения можно поэкспериментировать. Тем более, что все возможные простые - это строго определенные позиции в числ. ряду (30n+[1,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]). "Кратные" 8.

Comment: @avp Но я не думаю, что оно будет меньше, чем чистый бинарник. Все простые меньше 1 млрд занимают 33 333  334 байта.

Comment: Начать с того, что при `n == 18 446 744 073 709 551 615` мы получим нулевой длины вектор... :) Это понятно? Да и при других больших значениях даже в 64-разрядном варианте слет по памяти...

Comment: Если считать, что с 64-битовыми числами вы погорячились, и ограничиться 2000000000 — то ваша программа выдает на моей машине 98222287 за 17 с лишним секунд, программа из ответа к указанному мною вопросу — примерно за 8 секунд. Это просто к вашему "что я там должен увидеть"...

Comment: @Harry То не я, лонг там было. Мне лень было его убирать. ) У меня 1 млрд 350 сек. считает. Что-то пробовать честно говоря уже нет желания. Это ж я чисто из интереса страдал, а энтузиазм ничем не подогреваемый быстро проходит. )) И да, там constexpr, (idx&0x0000003F)>>1) - это ускоряет работу. Но как я и говорил, это особенности языка, а не алгоритма. Если наколдовать на асме, думаю, еще более быстрого выполнения можно добиться.

Comment: Зачем "колдовать", если можно писать на языке высокого уровня? Вы все пытаетесь свести к тому, что если алгоритм достиг оптимальной *алгоритмической* эффективности, то этого достаточно в любом случае. Только вот иногда O(n^2) работает в реальной ситуации быстрее, чем O(n log n), например... Так и тут. Использование `vector<bool>`, который использует прокси-класс для обращения к элементам, уже хорошо гасит производительность...

Comment: Согласен. Только заметьте, что я свожу не просто к "достаточно", а к "для меня достаточно, ибо никакой практической пользы и надоело" ))

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> int* parr = new int[n];
> ```

```
int* parr = new int[n+1];
```

---

А ещё, нерационально хранить в массиве сами числа. Числом является индекс, а массив можно сделать массивом bool'ов - тогда он будет занимать в 4 раза меньше места. Можно и до битов пожать, но тогда может на производительности сказаться.